# restful client using token authentification with php

Tags: php

I am trying to access a restful API using token authentification but I am getting the following error:

```
"ErrorCode": "InvalidAuthenticationHeader",
"Message": "Invalid authentication information was passed in Authetication Header!"
```

Comment: This information can't help other to fix your problem. Share your API/php code for this

Comment: are you using postman or you are trying to run it browser directly?B'cos if header is not passed it will not go further to execute WS

Comment: I am working in a lunix server...I use "php fileName.php" to run

Comment: Do you really think that without knowing the api vendor, without knowing your code someone can help you?